# Clear access list to a chat room

Tags: support, chat

We want to clean up the access to our chat room. Having 1.4k users added/restricted we are looking for a way to revoke access from everybody except the owners and grant write access to the regulars again.

Is there any possibility to get this done without touching 1.4k users and revoke the access manually?

Comment: Create a new room? And how the hell did you add that many users to the acces list?

Comment: The Android room is old. And pretty popular. We managed it somehow :P

Comment: Creating a new room is a bad option as we'd lose around 350k of past messages.

Comment: That's what happens when you decide to be all restrictive.  :)  Suck it up and start clicking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a one-off case like that, there's not really a UI for it. Let me know what precisely you want changed (in particular, which room we are talking about), and I'll do it on the backend.

Comment: We're talking about [Room 15](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android). We essentially want everyone except room owners to be removed from the request access and write access list. If possible, we'd like to keep the read only list as it is.

Comment: Yes this would be awesome. Feel free to drop in for further information!

Comment: @WarrenFaith Okay, I'll try to get to it tomorrow.

Comment: why don't you want the occasional users who can ask questions and participate in the events in that room @WarrenFaith? Is that room specially designed for only those 7 owners?

Comment: @SreeCharan They have a community and an ethos. Considering that we are shared owners of a gallery room and we have people that we lock out for asking questions that don't fit within that ethos, why would you want to restrict what the Android Room owners do with their access list?

Comment: We essentially want everyone except room owners to be removed from the request access and write access list. <-- watch this comment and do you think all the 1400 members wont come under there ethos? Anyway, never mind, but that won't look like a programming language specific room, that will look like a room specific for owners.

Comment: @SreeCharan You missed the bit in the question about "granting access to the room regulars again" They don't want to have a room just for the owners, but they want to clean up their access list to a core group while maintaining a read-only list and then look at granting access to people as they request it.

Comment: We are ready when you are :)

Comment: well, Good choice @WarrenFaith as there are 1.4k users. Atlast, i agree with you.